# Matlab: How to plot values while calculating them?

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there any way in matlab to plot values as you go? Somehow passing the plot function the x and y values one at time? I have a really costly for loop and I think the only way around using plot directly in a loop (I think I saw this in someone's code) might be saving each y value in an array. This however gives me an error such as : **`Attempted to access Y(1.00202); index must be a positive integer or logical.`**

Example code:

```
function n = get_nodes(x_s, x_e, e_k)
    y_prev = 0; y_curr = 1;
    h = 10^-5;
    n = 0;
    for x = x_s+0.1:h:x_e-0.1
        a = 2 + (5/6)*forcing(x, e_k)*h^2;
        b = 1 - (1/12)*forcing(x-h, e_k)*h^2;
        c = 1 - (1/12)*forcing(x+h, e_k)*h^2;
        y_next = (a * y_curr + b * y_prev)/c;
        y_prev = y_curr;
        y_curr = y_next;
        if (y_next == e_k) 
            n = n + 1;
        end
        % gives empty plot 
        plot(x, y_curr);
    end   

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kedarp's answer shows how to update the plot point by point, but you also mentioned not being able to store the values as you go due to indexing issues.

This approach also tidies up your code, removing the need for `y_curr`, `y_next` and `y_prev`, it likely runs a bit quicker because of it:

```
function n = get_nodes(x_s, x_e, e_k)
    h = 10^-5;
    n = 0;
    x = x_s+0.1:h:x_e-0.1; % Set up x vector
    y = zeros(size(x));    % pre-allocate vector for y_curr values
    y(2) = 1;              % You previously called this y_curr, already y_prev = Y(1) = 0
    for ii = 3:numel(x)    % notice in particular that the loop starts from 3, for y(ii-2)
        a = 2 + (5/6)*forcing(x(ii), e_k)*h^2;
        b = 1 - (1/12)*forcing(x(ii)-h, e_k)*h^2;
        c = 1 - (1/12)*forcing(x(ii)+h, e_k)*h^2;
        % Assign next y value, swapping which value is current happens naturally
        y(ii) = (a * y(ii-1) + b * y(ii-2))/c;           
    end     
    n = sum(y == e_k);     % now we have y stored, we can get n outside the loop
    plot(x,y)              % can just plot all at once...
end
```

---

Edit: if you were being even cleverer, you would take the `a,b,c` calculations outside of the `for` loop too! You're calculating `forcing(x(ii), e_k)` 3 times for every `ii`, since you do the 3 neighbouring points each time.

If you set up `forcing` so that it could take a vector `x`, you could call `f = forcing(x, e_k)` *once*, and then you can define `a`,`b` and `c` and simply iterate over `y` within the loop. **That would certainly save time.**

Comment: Wow this really worked like a charm and your suggestions are very much appreciated. Forcing is used in other functions with a single parameter, not sure if you can make functions with variable number of params or check if array is passed?

Comment: You will want to look into "element-wise operations" (using a dot before standard operators) and maybe `bsxfun`, these will help you make functions which work for both scalars and vectors, Matlab efficiency is all about vectorisation!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go plotting while you compute, you need to define the line from the previous point to the current one in the loop, and hold the previous pots. You can change your plotting lines to:

```
    hold on
    plot([x-h x],[y_prev y_curr]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no points in plot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting plot handle objects for plotting in a loop as opposed to creating a new plot each time. For example,

```
x = 1:100;
% Initialise plot handle
h = plot(nan,nan);

for iter = 1:1e2
   y = rand + rand*x + rand*(x.^2 );
   % set appropriate values of handle
   set(h, {'XData','YData'}, {x, y});
   drawnow;
end
```

This way, a `plot`  handle is created only once, and its properties are set in the loop.